# How do I control which 'Google My Business' images show in the Google search results?

Tags: images, google-my-business

In Google My Business I want to change the photos that are marked with the red and blue squares in the image below, and specifically which forms in the Google My Business admin relate to the photo marked red and the same with the photo marked blue.

When logged into the Google My Business admin I can see ( among others ) :

- Profile Photo
- Cover Photo
- Logo

I want my logo to appear where the red square is; so I've made all three of the above slots have my logo in them - but instead it's putting in a different photo ( as shown ) which is not representative of my business at all.

Which photo field in the Google My Business admin should I be changing to get my logo into that slot ( or any photo representaive of my business)?

Then similarly with the blue square, how do I change that photo?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Stephen but I actually phrased it that way because I wanted to know which those photos particularly related to - ie is the one in red and blue the profile, cover or what? I know it's shorter but it's not actually asking exactly what I wanted to ask really.The way you have it just asks how to change "the photos", not the specific photos marked each in red and blue. I can't think of a more succinct way of asking my question myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google won't always obey instructions on which photos to use, and where in the knowledge graph to feature them, as you just found out. But you can better the chances by following certain guidelines.

Your profile photo won't show up anywhere in the Knowledge Graph. It'll be featured in the upper right corner of your account.

Your logo is great to have for image search and for Google's own info, but it rarely gets featured in the Knowledge Graph for local results. (Though it sometimes is; it just isn't frequent.)

Your cover photo has the best chance of making it in and being featured. For the properties I manage, we use colorful, attractive cover photos, and they usually make it into the local result. If your cover photo contains your logo, it might make it in, but keep in mind, it might get cropped on top and bottom (your blue square) and there isn't much you'll be able to do about it.

Follow Google's guidelines for photo size and file type. Read more here: https://support.google.com/business/answer/6103862?hl=en

Google also likes to show pictures of your location from outside. Those don't always look best; sometimes they're just ugly Google Earth shots. You can take your own picture and upload it. More here: https://support.google.com/business/answer/160464?hl=en

You may have to experiment some more with your photos, sizes, etc. before getting the desired result. (Which, again, is still not guaranteed.)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try experimenting. I can't use a photo of my business because I just work from home online so it's just a photo of a family house which is not representative at all. Actually, a lot of businesses similar to mine have the same issue with ( as in my case ) a picture of a hedge or a mountain or a house. The only thing that will properly represent my business is either a logo or a selection of my works. So I've grabbed a screenshot of some of those to see how that will work.

Comment: Strangely though a few of my competitors have their logo in, and in fact I did a google my business page for a client a while back and her logo went in fine. It wasn't even a particularly good logo. I don't know what I did to get it in there however - are there any guidelines to getting logos displayed in the knowledge graph

Comment: @byronyasgur Sometimes the logos do make it in. If the only or best photo is a logo, Google may choose to just display it, for example. Or if you design a cover photo that's basically your logo, but adheres to cover photo specs. Also, if you mark up your logo on your website with specific structured data, you might get that into the Knowledge Graph; more here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo